# How $\|f\|=\sup\left\{\frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{\|x\|}:x \ne 0,x\in X \right\}$ and $\|f\|=\sup\{\vert f(x)\vert:\|x\|=1 ,x\in X \}$ are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

A linear functional $f$ on a normed space $X$ is said to be bounded if there is a constant $K\gt0$ such that  $$\vert f\vert 
\le K \|x\|,\quad\forall x\in X\tag{1}$$

The smallest constant $K$ for which $(1)$ holds is called the norm of $f$.
Then,

$$\|f\|=\sup\left\{\frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{\|x\|}:x \ne 0,x\in X \right\}\tag{2}$$

or  equivalently $$\|f\|=\sup\left\{\vert f(x)\vert:\|x\|=1 ,x\in X \right\}\tag{3}$$

I'm not getting how $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent?

Comment: we must assume that $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}\subset \Bbb F$, where $\Bbb F$ is the field of the vector space $X$, then $\|x\|\in\Bbb F$ and the linearity of $f$ explain the result.

Comment: @Masacroso:I'm not getting what you want to convey.Will you please explain little bit about your idea about your assumptions?What if the assumptions you made are dropped?

Comment: If $\|x\|\in\Bbb F$ then, because $f$ is linear, then $f(y)/\|x\|=f(y/\|x\|)$. If $\|x\|\notin\Bbb F$ then $f(x)/\|x\|$ is not defined in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the linearity of $f$ and the properties of the norm: note that
$$ \frac{|f(x)|}{||x||}=\Big|\,f\Big(\frac{x}{||x||}\Big)\Big|=|f(u_x)| $$
where $u_x=\frac{x}{||x||}$ satisfies $||u_x||=1$. Therefore taking the supremum over either set yields the same result:

Indeed, if we let
$$ S_1=\sup\{\frac{|f(x)|}{||x||}:x\neq 0\}$$
and 
$$ S_2=\sup\{|f(x)|:||x||=1\} $$
then $S_2\leq S_1$ since the second set is contained in the first. But on the other hand, for any $x\neq 0$ we have
$$ \frac{|f(x)|}{||x||}=|f(u_x)|\leq S_2 $$
so taking the supremum over all $x\neq 0$ yields $S_1\leq S_2$.